# How to unit test a XML document to string transformation method

Tags: java, dom, junit

```
public static String convertDocumentToString(Document xmlDocument) {

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xmlDocument), new StreamResult(writer));

            return writer.getBuffer().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am trying to unit test (junit) the following method
what would be the easiest/simplest approach to creating the document in the unit test?

Any suggestions? Mockito isn't something feasible here

for example the test

```
1. @Test
1. public void convertDocumentToString() {
1. Document document = ??
1. 
1. class.convertDocumentToString(document)
```

how would I build a Document variable to pass to the method

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple XML document using `DocumentBuilder`:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        Document xmlDocument = createDocument();

        String result = new MyTransformer().convertDocumentToString(xmlDocument);

        String expected = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><root><element>value</element></root>";

        assertEquals(expected, result);
    }

    private Document createDocument() throws Exception {

        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .newDocument();

        // Create root element
        Element rootElement = document.createElement("root");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        // Create child element
        Element childElement = document.createElement("element");
        childElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("value"));

        rootElement.appendChild(childElement);

        return document;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest/easiest way is just to parse an XML string and verify that you get the same string back:

```
@Test
void test() throws Exception {
    var xml = """
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><root/>""";
    
    var doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newDefaultInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    assertEquals(xml, convertDocumentToString(doc));
}
```

Note that there is an implicit static import of `convertDocumentToString`.

Testing that the method returns null on an exception will be quite difficult since the transformer delivers the XML prolog even if the input document is null or empty, and constructing an illegal Document structure should not be possible (there might be some corner cases).

Returning null on an exception is actually hiding a severe error condition. Something is wrong with the platform/setup of java itself. I recommend throwing a custom RuntimeException instead.